Condicion if parece interferir otra, Falla de compilador?. Buffer de cout?
En la primer jugada su_puntaje dá 8 cuando deberia sumar 3.
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

uint mi_puntaje = 0;
uint su_puntaje = 0;

void jugada(bool yo = 1, bool el = 1) {
    cout << "jugada\n ";
    if (yo == true && el == false) mi_puntaje += 10;

    if (yo == false && el == true) su_puntaje += 10;

    if (yo == false && el == false) mi_puntaje += 3;
    su_puntaje += 3;

    if (yo == true && el == true) mi_puntaje += 5;
    su_puntaje += 5;
    cout << mi_puntaje << endl;

    cout << su_puntaje << endl;
}

int main() {
    jugada(0, 0);
    jugada(0, 1);
    jugada(1, 0);
    return 0;
}

Programo en celular, en sololearn compila sumando 8. En otras aplicaciones dá error en línea donde solicito la impresión.
La IA sugiere que podría depender del compilador.Es así?. Tendrá que ver con el buffer de cout?.
Agradezco la comprehensión que puedan brindarme de éste error.

Hay otras páginas que funcionan mejor en celular, a mí me gustan https://tio.run, https://ideone.com/ y https://nextleap.app/online-compiler/c-programming. Por cierto, si la variable es de tipo bool, if (variable == true) es lo mismo que simplemente if(variable) y if (variable == false) es lo mismo que if (!variable)

Gracias por tu tiempo y los datos. Probé esas páginas y suma mal, no es el compilador.

Edité tu pregunta solo para darle formato al código. La lógica sigue siendo la misma de antes.
Es probable que tal y como lo tenías antes no veías bien el problema:
if (yo == false && el == false) mi_puntaje += 3;
su_puntaje += 3;

if (yo == true && el == true) mi_puntaje += 5;
su_puntaje += 5;

El if sin llaves solo ejecuta la siguiente instrucción. Si lo que quieres es ejecutar varias instrucciones, necesitas un bloque de código delimitado por llaves.
Así deberías obtener el resultado esperado:
if (yo == false && el == false) {
    mi_puntaje += 3;
    su_puntaje += 3;
}

if (yo == true && el == true) {
    mi_puntaje += 5;
    su_puntaje += 5;
}

Lo mismo sucede con otras instrucciones de control de flujo como el else, while y do.
No olvides darle formato a tu código, te ayudará a ver los problemas más fácilmente.

Exactamente esto, pero Mateo, puedes agregar una descripción exacta del problema? para que sea explícito para el resto de las personas.

Genial, muchas gracias

@Excorpion "El if sin llaves solo ejecuta la siguiente instrucción" no es explícito? Qué me sugieres?

Me refería a poner su código, indicando el error, perdón si me expliqué mal :P

@Excorpion ah ok, qué tal así?

Perfecto! lo decía por que yo mismo no entendí rapidamente el problema, yo solo veía la identación, hasta que mas tarde noté que era en línea.
